# Disabling basic authentication with spring security ldap

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I'm trying to set up a basic spring-security-ldap authentication with a login-form, but when i try to log in I still get a http-basic popup, which doesn't allow login.

My security.xml:

```
<s:http>
  <s:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
  <s:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER,ROLE_READONLY" />
  <s:form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true"
            login-processing-url="/j_security_check"
            default-target-url="/mainMenu.html"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
  <s:logout />
</s:http>

<s:ldap-server url="${ldap.url}"
             manager-dn="${ldap.adm_username}"
             manager-password="${ldap.adm_password}"/>

<s:authentication-manager>
  <s:ldap-authentication-provider user-search-filter="(cn={0})"
                                  user-search-base="${ldap.user_search_base}"
                                  group-search-base="ou=myapp,ou=mysystem,o=ACME"
                                  role-prefix="none"/>
</s:authentication-manager>
```

From web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

    <!-- First filter-mapping in file -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is part of a refactoring job, and when comparing to a deployed version of how it was before refactoring, the url `(server):(port)/(webapproot)/j_security_check` is not available, but it is available after the refactoring, and prompts a basic login box, which is also what pops up when trying to log in through the login-page.

[image: Login box]

When trying to login through the login-box, i get this stacktrace in the server log:

```
[#|2013-02-26T12:41:30.411+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security|_ThreadID=333;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Failed file login for .
      at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:394)
      at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:240)
      at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:153)
      at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:483)
      at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:425)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:176)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:909)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:487)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
      at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
      at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
      at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
      at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
      at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
      at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
      at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
      at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
      at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
      at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
      at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
      at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
      at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
      at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
      at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
      at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Failed file login for .
      at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.FileLoginModule.authenticate(FileLoginModule.java:84)
      at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:117)
      at com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule.login(AppservPasswordLoginModule.java:148)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784)
      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698)
      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695)
      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594)
      at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:382)
      ... 29 more
    |#]
```

How do I disable the basic-login, and what am I missing in order to make the authentication against the ldap-server?

Update:

I changed the glassfish security realm to ldap-realm, and set it up as it was on the old glassfish server. Also, I disabled the "security manager" in glassfish. Now, I still get the extra pop-up login box, but the stacktrace looks better:

```
    [#|2013-02-26T13:47:49.640+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception
    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Access denied on empty password for user .
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:394)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:240)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:153)
        at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:483)
        at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:425)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Access denied on empty password for user .
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LDAPLoginModule.authenticate(LDAPLoginModule.java:102)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:117)
        at com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule.login(AppservPasswordLoginModule.java:148)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:382)
        ... 29 more
    |#]
```

But how do I disable glassfish's security mechanism all together, and only rely on the spring one?

Update #2: Found the culprit. I had this in default-web.xml in my glassfish installation:

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Removed it, and no more login-box :) Off to the next problem then :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic authentication is not handled by Spring Security. Look into the stack trace. There are no Spring Security filters. It looks like your basic authentication is handled by Glassfish itself. Try to disable basic authentication trough Glassfish. Do you have **login-config** and **security-constraint** tags in the web.xml? If it's true then just remove them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am looking into glassfish atm (the refactoring also included moving to a newer glassfish version), and in the old server I see that there is a security realm set up against my ldap-server, which is not in the setup of the new one. I will try adding it and see what happens.

Comment: Do you have login-config and security-constraint tags in the web.xml?

Comment: Not in the web.xml of my project, no. I must say I find it difficult to seperate between glassfish's security realm and the one configured with Spring, and trying to learn from a quite messy project doesn't make it easier. At the moment I'm not sure whether the spring setup or the glassfish setup is what provides the authentication setup..

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is not Spring Security. Make a brakepoint in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(...) method. It's entry point for all Spring Security magic. I am sure it will be not called.

Comment: I think I might have found (one of) the problem(s). In the new Glassfish server, "Security manager" was enabled, in the old it was not. Trying now to disable it on the new server, hopefully I won't get the login-box when I try to log in.